# Is using Elastic Search as authoritative datastore for applications advisable?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to using elastic search, and I'm trying to find a datastore for our application where we can also add a front end for analytics, in this case Kibana. I'm planning to use them as a datastore for dr/cr transactions on our billing system.

Most use case I read is towards data analytics and searching related. I don't see a use case wherein it is used as a regular datastore for an application. So I'm worried I might use it on a wrong use case.

I was hoping if anyone can add their insights on this. Like why or why not use Elastic Search as authoritative/primary datastore for applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read a [official blog of elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-elasticsearch-as-nosql), where they clearly mentioned that databases must be robust and should not stop working unless you tell to do it.

From the [robustness section](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-elasticsearch-as-nosql#robustness) of same blog

> A database should be robust, especially if it is your authoritative
> system of record. Ideally, a costly query should be possible to
> cancel, and you certainly don't want the database to stop working
> unless you tell it to.
>
> **Unfortunately, Elasticsearch (and the components it's made of) does
> not currently handle OutOfMemory-errors very well.** We cover this in
> more depth in Elasticsearch in Production, OutOfMemory-Caused Crashes.
> It is very important to provide Elasticsearch with enough memory and
> be careful before running searches with unknown memory requirements on
> a production cluster.

**In short, you shouldn't use Elasticsearch as a primary data-store where you can't afford to loose the data.**